# AJAX Method does not get initiated after the autocomplete method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So what the code does is it gives item suggestions to the user based on the contents of the database (items table).

After clicking the right item suggestion the next method (ajax) will now retrieve another column (item price) based on the clicked suggestion to display the price of the item in the second text box.

It is already working when the two methods are separated so I guess the error is  in the index.php script. There are also no errors that pops up so I really need the help

**Index.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Auto Complete Input box</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#itemTravel").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    selectFirst: true
    });

    function showRoom(){
    var itemNamed = $("#itemTravel").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"process.php",
        data:{action:"showroom", itemName: itemNamed },
        success:function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
}
showRoom();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <label>Tag:</label>
    <input name="tag" type="text" id="itemTravel" size="20"/>
    <input name="number" type="text" id="itemPrice" size="20"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phpcollab");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

$action=$_POST["action"];
$itemName=$_POST["itemName"];
if($action=="showroom"){
    echo $itemName;
    $query="SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemName='".$itemName."'";
    $show=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die ("Error");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($show);
    echo $row['price'];
    echo "<script>
            document.getElementById('itemPrice').value = '".$row['price']."';
            </script>";

}
?>
```

**autocomplete.php**

```
    <?php
 $q=$_GET['q'];
 $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','phpcollab') or die("Database Error");
 $sql="SELECT name FROM tag WHERE name LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY name";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

 if($result)
 {
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo $row['name']."\n";
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You need to trigger the function 'showRoom()' when the value for your input has changed, now you only trigger it on page load.

Comment: Please try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will allow us to quickly identify and help with your problem. Cleaning out any irrelevant code helps a ton when you have a lot to look through!